# Omniauth facebook - fetch friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to configure omniauth-facebook to fetch user friends.

This is my configuration:

```
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, "xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx",
      :info_fields => 'friends'
end
```

I am using Rails 2.3.

I am using this code in view:

```
<div id="contacts">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  $('contacts').innerHTML = '<%= request.env['omniauth.auth'].keys %>';
</script>
```

I am not sure why the script  is not being executed, but when I copy:

```
  $('contacts').innerHTML = 'infouidcredentialsextraprovider';
```

in console after page has loaded it works replacing content of div with that text.

There is no error message in browser console.

Why script does not get executed? I tried with console.log too, and I had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `info_fields` option is still new and so you will have to wait for a [new release](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/releases) of the [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) gem.

In the meantime, you can try using the master branch by changing your Gemfile to:

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook', :github => 'mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook'
```

As for debugging, you can get the information returned from facebook by adding the following as the first line of your callback controller:

```
raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
```

Now try to login and you'll be able to take a good look at the hash of nested hashes returned.

Comment: @biomancer, your edit was wrongly rejected, but I edited the typo anyway. Thanks!